# Virtual box not working on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 15.04

I have problem with virtual box.
It worked fine for some time then after update on ubuntu 15.04 I am getting this error:

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no
>   module
>            available for the current kernel (3.16.0-34-generic) or it failed to
>            load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
>        sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
>
>      You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```

I can run Virtual box but I can't run any virtual machine inside of it, I get this error

> The virtual machine 'Win XP2' has terminated unexpectedly during
>   startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
>
> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component:  MachineWrap
>   Interface:  IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}

Any help would be great, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` ? It needs `build-essential` pcket installed too.

Comment: Which version is Virtual Box?

Comment: After runing sudo /etc/int.d/vboxdrv setup i got this error:
`Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-34-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)`

Comment: Also I use Virtualbox 5.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, installed latest kernel and header files for it, then I run:
`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`